# Loading PNG from resources in Netbeans Java

Tags: java, png

I have a project where I am loading *.PNG images from the project resources.  I found that some PNG files load ok and others are not found by .getClass().getResource(fileName), which returns null.

The failure appears to be dependent on the actual format of the PNG.  I have some older PNGs that load ok, but when I make new ones in GIMP they consistently fail to load.  (And er - I've forgotten how I made the older ones…)

The images are all 16x16 and are all in the project Source Packages/resources.

I tried saving PNGs in many different formats in GIMP, but all have failed to work.

I am loading them with:

```
protected ImageIcon loadIcon(String fileName) {
    Class<?> cls = this.getClass();
    URL url = cls.getResource(fileName);
    // ⬅️ this is the point of failure as url will be null

    if (url == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        msglistener.Send(new EMsgData.Builder().setType(EMsgData.MsgType.DEBUG).setSender(this).setText("Load Icon Failed").build());
    }

    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return new ImageIcon(image);
}
```

Where the argument would typically be:
ImageIcon icon = loadIcon("/Pencil.png");

I've attached two images. The first one fails and the second one works.

[image: this is a nonworking png]

[image: This is a working png]

Comment: I have never encountered a PNG file that ImageIO could not load.  Can you add an example image to your question?

Comment: *// this is the point of failure as url will be null* In that case, it's *far* more likely that you're passing the wrong string to the `loadIcon` method. The variable name `fileName` is a red flag, as what you need is a package-relative url, *not* a file name. *Yes* there might be overlap but generally you want something like `/images/x.png` `/Pencil.png` would work *if* its at the root of your package tree

Comment: Filename is bit erronous.  It is acutally a package relative url, as indicated in the comments.

Comment: Both png's are fine.

Comment: I'm completely at a loss as to why one won't load on my setup...

Comment: Is your project driven by Maven or Gradle?

Comment: From the symptoms, I think it's just that the resources are not loaded from the *source* folder, they are loaded from the compiled output folder (typically named `target` or `classes` or something like this, I don't use NetBeans, so I don't know the exact name). Maybe you just need to tune your compiler/output settings to that NetBeans correctly copies the resources to the output folder? Old files are probably already there, new ones are not.

Answer (score 0):

### `Objects.requireNonNull`

Tip: You can more conveniently check for nulls by using [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)). For example:

```
ImageIcon iconA = new ImageIcon ( Objects.requireNonNull ( urlA ) );
```

### Working example, using Maven

I do not know exactly what your problem is. But I can give you a working example. I used your exact two linked files, and both work for me.

[image: screenshot of demo app with four JLabel objects displayed, two text and two icons]

#### `resources` folder

If you use [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) to drive the build of your project, create a folder named exactly `resources` at the top of the `main` folder within your `src` folder. Any nested files and folders found in `resources` will be copied into the final artifact (your JAR file) when you build the project.

Here is a screenshot from [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). Doing the same in [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) should work as well. Ditto [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)).

Notice how the two PNG files in `resources` appear in the `target` folder as part of the build process. No `resources` folder in the result, just the contents of `resources` are transferred in the build process.

[image: screenshot of project structure showing how contents of "resources" folder are copied to top of the final JAR file artifact by Apache Maven]

And here is the code for this example app. Written in Java 21 on a Mac. Should work with much earlier versions of Java as well, and should work across platforms.

Note that the `/` notation in the [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG) file names means a path from the top level of the [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file at runtime. Technically this is the default [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath) from what I could discern in a quick web-search, but I am no expert on this aspect.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Demonstrate loading PNG files as ImageIcon for display in Swing app.
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Hello World!" );
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ( )
        {
            public void run ( )
            {
                createAndShowGUI ( );
            }
        } );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        // JFrame
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true );
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Icons" );
        frame.setLayout ( new FlowLayout ( ) );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // Widgets
        URL urlA = App.class.getResource ( "/4eS8f.png" );
        ImageIcon iconA = new ImageIcon ( Objects.requireNonNull ( urlA ) );
        JLabel labelA = new JLabel ( Objects.requireNonNull ( iconA ) );

        URL urlB = App.class.getResource ( "/ENwj0.png" );
        ImageIcon iconB = new ImageIcon ( Objects.requireNonNull ( urlB ) );
        JLabel labelB = new JLabel ( Objects.requireNonNull ( iconB ) );

        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( new JLabel ( "Hello World" ) );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( labelA );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( labelB );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( new JLabel ( "The End" ) );

        // Display.
        frame.pack ( );
        frame.setSize ( 400 , 200 );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

}
```

#### Grouping your image files into a folder

To be more organized, you may want to group those icon image files together in a folder.

Let's make a folder named `icons`, into which we nest our PNG files. Add that word `icons` to our file name arguments. Ex: `"/icons/4eS8f.png"`. You [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) might even update those file name arguments automagically.

We get the same results as above by changing the string argument in these two lines:

```java
        URL urlA = App.class.getResource ( "/icons/4eS8f.png" );
        …

        URL urlB = App.class.getResource ( "/icons/ENwj0.png" );
```

#### POM

Here is my modified version of the POM file coming from the Maven archetype [Quickstart](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Iconify</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Iconify</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0-M9</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.5</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you fo ryour help.  I am 100% mystified by this.

I can take a working icon, open it in an image editing program, and save it unchanged, but with a new name.  And it then won't load!

I'm wondering if this is something to do with the way the system is handling images...  I'm using Win10.  I've never managed to get Netbeans to load a *.BMP.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the resouces folder was in the wrong place in NetBeans.  Maven is expecting it to be src/main/resouces, however I had simply added a resources folder to Source package in the project tree, which then creates a folder in src/main/java/resouces.  This means that Maven doesn't find out.

However what is puzzling is that Maven was finding old resouces in the first location, but not finding ones that I added recently.  I can only think that this is related to my updating from a very old version of Java to the latest version, but this doesn't really explain why after a clean a build on the project the old resouces were still found.

I found that the existing resouce was found and loaded ok, but if I renamed it (and tried to load the renamed version) it failed.  So the PGN format thing was entirely a red herring.  (I did learn a lot about PNGs along the way...)

The restult is that now it work, but I'm still unsure as to how it was loading any resources in the first place.  I'm also not 100% certain that I am correctly locating the resources in NetBeans.

Also apologies for the later response, but I had to have some urgent health checks - all which turned out to be ok.  Thanks for everyone's help.